# Каким образом свойство в прототипе участвует в записи

Tags: javascript, прототипное-наследование

В интернете много где, например, [тут](https://learn.javascript.ru/prototype-inheritance#operatsiya-zapisi-ne-ispolzuet-prototip), утверждается, что при записи свойства в объект, даже если такого свойства в объекте еще нет, но есть в прототипе,  свойство просто создастся в объекте без участия прототипа.
То есть предполагается, что если есть

```
const animal = {
  name: 'somename',
};

const cat = {
  __proto__: animal,
};
```

и я сделаю `cat.name = 'Васька'`, то name из animal вообще никак не будет задействован.
Однако если свойству name  у animal поставить дескриптор `writable = false`, то при записи свойства у cat возникнет ошибка.

```js
'use strict';

const animal = {
  name: 'somename',
};

const cat = {
  __proto__: animal,
};

Object.defineProperty(animal, 'name', { writable: false });

cat.name = 'Васька';
console.log(cat);
```

Объясните, пожалуйста, какая все-таки очередность действий происходит при такой записи.

Comment: А в хроме под линупс нет ошибки на присваивании (ее вроде и по спеке не должно быть)... хотя и собственное свойство у `cat` не создается (т.е., происходит то же самое что и при попытке изменения незаписываемого свойства - такая попытка просто игнорируется).

Comment: да, не уточнил, ошибка в строгом режиме. В обычном просто игнорируется действие

Comment: Самое простое предположение - может быть так что интерпретатор сначала вычисляет оба операнда `=` (в левой части выражения ища референс на свойство / контекстную запись... а т.к. собственного свойства у объекта нет, берет реф на прототипное), и только затем пытается по этому рефу производить запись значения, т.е. саму операцию присваивания. Если действительно так происходит, то получается что единственным способом создания собственного свойства в таких случаях остается все тот же статический метод `defineProperty` (он вроде не ходит по цепочке прототипов, но я точно не помню, врать не буду).

Comment: все, немного сложнее, и утверждение _при записи свойства в объект, даже если такого свойства в объекте еще нет, но есть в прототипе, свойство просто создастся в объекте без участия прототипа_ - работает в таком виде только для data-свойств у которых writable стоит `true`.

Comment: Что интересно, данное поведение может меняться в зависимости от типа объекта, которому присваивается свойство

Comment: yar85, Grundy
Спасибо

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Рассмотрим, что происходит при выполнении [оператора присваивания](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-assignment-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation)

В случае обычного присваивания вызывается внутренний метод [`PutValue`](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-putvalue), в который параметрами передается новое значение, и куда его нужно установить.

Если погрузиться в алгоритм [`PutValue`](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-putvalue) станет интересен пункт 6

```
b. Пусть succeeded будет результатом выполнения ? base.[[Set]](GetReferencedName(V), W, GetThisValue(V)).
c. Если succeeded равно false и строгий режим, тогда кинуть TypeError исключение.
```

Как можно заметить, если внутренний метод [`[[Set]]`](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-ordinary-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots-set-p-v-receiver) вернет `false`, будет кинуто исключение, что и происходит в случае кода в вопросе.

Чтобы разобраться, почему возвращается `false` нужно погрузиться немного глубже, а именно в метод [`OrdinarySet`](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-ordinaryset), который получает текущий дескриптор свойства в объекте, если он есть и передает в [`OrdinarySetWithOwnDescriptor`](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-ordinarysetwithowndescriptor)

В случае, если переданный дескриптор свойства - `undefined`, и у объекта есть `prototype` - вернется результат вызова [`[[Set]]`](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-ordinary-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots-set-p-v-receiver) у прототипа, с переданным `Receiver` - который ссылается на текущий объект.

В случае если у объекта нет прототипа просто создается PropertyDescriptor со значением по умолчанию

```
{ [[Value]]: undefined, [[Writable]]: true, [[Enumerable]]: true, [[Configurable]]: true }
```

Важно обратить внимание на значение `[[Writable]]: true`.

Далее проверяем, что полученный PropertyDescriptor является [DataProperty](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-isdatadescriptor), то есть у него есть хотя бы одно из свойств `[[Value]]`, `[[Writable]]`, в этом случае происходит следующее:

1. если `[[Writable]]: false` - вернуть `false`
2. если Type(Receiver) не `Object`, вернуть `false`
3. проверяет наличие нужного свойства у `Receiver` и если оно есть

   1. проверяется значение `[[Writable]]`: если `[[Writable]]: false` - вернуть `false`
   2. устанавливается новое значение свойства
4. если данного свойства нет:

   1. просто создается данное свойство у Receiver.

---

Рассмотрим что происходит в коде в вопросе:

1. попадаем в метод `OrdinarySetWithOwnDescriptor`, в котором параметр `ownDesc` принимает значение `undefined`, так как такого свойства нет в объекте `cat`. В качестве `Receiver` передается сам объект `cat`
2. так как `ownDesc == undefined`, но у `cat` есть прототип `animal` берем его и вызываем `[[Set]]` уже для него и
3. попадаем в метод `OrdinarySetWithOwnDescriptor`, в котором параметр `ownDesc` принимает значение

   ```
    {value: 'somename', writable: false, enumerable: true, configurable: true}`
   ```

   так как нужное свойство есть в объекте `animal`. В качестве `Receiver` все еще передается объект `cat`.
4. `ownDesc` является `DataProperty`, а значит происходит переход к следующей проверке
5. `[[Writable]]: false` - в данном случае поле уже `writable: false` - поэтому происходит возврат `false`, как результат - ошибка в строгом режиме.

Comment: Очень подробно и доступно (насколько доступность вообще возможна при таких сложных вещах). Благодаря ответу, до меня наконец-то дошло написанное в спецификации. Спасибо!

Comment: Спасибо огромное, все очень подробно и понятно!